# Error opeing android emulator on Android studio on macbook air m1

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I have tried a lot to find the solution. but found nothing. After opeing emulator, I am going to connect and run the flutter app. but it shows the following message:

INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.23.0 (build_id 11150993) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath /Users/abusufian/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a/ INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 1313 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.

[Error message in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt8t9.jpg)

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
emulator -avd "avd-name" -qemu -uuid "your own uuid"
```

Can you try running Emulator via this command and check if the issue persists?